# How to recalculate size when StackPanel Children changes?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a `Grid` with a `StackPanel` as header, something like this in XAML:

```xml
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Row="0">
            <Rectangle Height="100" Fill="Red" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
```

When I remove the red rectangle in C# code:

```
        HeaderPanel.Children.Clear()
```

It disappears but it still takes up space. I expected the `Auto` height `StackPanel` should collapse to 0 and the blue rectangle to take all the space of the grid. Can I make the sizes to be recalculated?

Platform is Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Manipulating UI elements in procedural code is discouraged in XAML-based technologies. That said, a `StackPanel` is an "infinite" container that does not resize itself depending on it's contents. Try using another `Grid`.

Comment: I guess it's not a problem with red `Rectangle` being visible or not, but that blue `Rectangle` must have its dimensions set.

Comment: @HighCore Point taken, but I need to manipulate UI in code. Changing the `StackPanel` to a `Grid` did unfortunately not help.

Comment: @amnezjak I do not want to set a fixed size of the blue rectangle but to use all space that is not used by the header.

Comment: Just ditch the `StackPanel` and put your `Rectangle` in the first row alone, forget that children clearing and instead apply a Collapsed/Visible directly to the Rectangle `Visibility` and voila, you'll have the behavior you desire. Cheers. :)

Comment: Or `HeaderPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Chris W.s comment, this is how I solved it. I changed the XAML to something like:

```xml
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Height="100" Fill="Red" x:Name="Header" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
```

Then in code I do:

```
        ContentPanel.Children.Remove(Header);
```

If I want to add an other header:

```
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle();
        r2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        r2.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        r2.Height = 50;
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(r2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this in a Windows Phone Silverlight project. I really wanted to keep the StackPanels so I found a workaround with the Height property. I have a method that fills the stack panel with UIElements:

```
private void LayoutStackPanel(IEnumerable<UIElement> elements)
{
    stackPanel.Children.Clear();
    if (elements.Count == 0)
    {
        stackPanel.Height = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // height must be removed or ui elements will overlap
        stackPanel.ClearValue(StackPanel.HeightProperty);
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            stackPanel.Children.Add(element);
        }
    }
}
```

I've only tested on Windows Phone but I think it would work on WPF as well.